# Using Python to get Emails, Always Connected

Tags: python

I'm using the following Python script to get new emails. However, I have to run this script every time to check or schedule a system to run the script.

Is it possible to keep an open connection and get emails as they come in? If so what impact will this have on my server?

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email@domain.com', 'password')

mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox")  # connect to inbox.

result, messages = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN")

if result == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].split():
        # Do Stuff
```

Comment: what about an infinite `while` loop and `sleep` function? You can break it like for example after 12 hours.

Comment: @howaboutNO how does this impact things, I use the same server to run other Django Python Apps, would this lock Python in anyway?

Comment: @OrbiterFleet No it won't lock python: You can run it in the background with &, or open a new python task from a different window (presuming you are running it from terminal). Moreover during the sleep function it wont really be using any processing power so it shouldn't affect other processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done similar things and generally keep the script as simple as possible, without loops, and just schedule it as a cron job.

The more complex you make it, the more chances it has to break.  What happens if you try to get mail and your session has expired?  Or you lost the network connection for a minute, or gmail is down for a moment?  Now you have to add try/except to keep the entire script from breaking down.

With a simple cron job, if it fails it's no big deal - cron will just try again in x minutes.

Comment: You know you make a very good point! Thanks for this. I was hoping there was some sort of socket/port, but your point makes sense.

Comment: What you would be looking for in terms of constant or persistent connections is a Python implementation of IMAP's push notifications.  The builtin libraries don't provide for this, though there are some that do.  In this instance, that kind of instant feedback is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop would be perfect for this. Breaking every 10 hours or so might be a good idea. Alternatively you could have it start check when you wake up and stop when you go to sleep. (Of course to deal with the late nights you should add something that has it check if you run the script really late, and update only one or twice.)

If you mean "my server" as in an email server, it won't have much of an effect. Essentially, it would be like refreshing your gmail inbox in person, which I know can be done for an hour at least. If you mean "my server" in the sense that this script would run on a remote server of yours, again this shouldn't be a problem. A Script this small would likely use only a little of your system resources. Unless your being emailed gigabytes of data a week, I don't expect the network to take a hit either, as the messages between the script and gmails server are not that large.